# How to push data to realtime database using a loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular-promise

I am trying to push data into the realtime database using a for loop as there are multiple entries. The am confused on how should multiple promises be handled. Please help.

```
     onSubmit() {
for(let i = 0; i < this.userList.length; i++) {

  this.mtcService.getUserCount(this.userList[i].$key).subscribe(
    ((ct) => {
      const Mtcount = ct.length;

      // pushing to realtime db =>
      this.mtcService.createUser(this.userList[i].$key, Mtcount, this.userForm.value)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Success ' + i);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    }),
    ((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  );


}
}


 getUserCount(id) {
return this.db.list('path1/path2/' + id).snapshotChanges();
}


createUser(path, count, data) {
return this.db.object('path3/path4/' + path + '/' + count).set(data);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, and what isn't working about it. But at first glance, you'll want to have a look at `Promise.all()`.

Comment: first i am getting a count from the database then using that count as key i am  trying to push different data for different users in the database

Comment: can you give me an idea on how to use the promise.all() function in my case

Comment: It's hard to give you an example now, since the code in your question seems to depend on things we can't see, such as `getUserCount` and `createUser`. Try to isolate the problem in a standalone piece of code, so that we can follow exactly what it does. Keep in mind there: if we need to read less code, it is more likely we can help. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
There are the two methods in my service file

getUserCount(id) {
        return this.db.list('path/path2/' + id).snapshotChanges();
      }

    createUser(path, count, data) {
        return this.db.object('path/path2/' + path + '/' + count).set(data);
      }

Comment: Given that the method is called `getUserCount`, it seems you are only looking to get this number once and then use it. If so, why aren't you [using a `get()` call to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)?

Answer (score 0):

```
  const promises = data.map(async (id) => {
    await Axios.post(URL);
  });
  await Promise.all(promises);
```